# directive or an assembly reference missing

Tags: c#

```
 PdfPageBase page = document.Pages.Add();             
 PdfGraphics graphics = page.Graphics;         //Creates a certificate instance from PFX file with private key.             
 PdfCertificate pdfCert = new PdfCertificate(@"PDF.pfx", "syncfusion");
```

when I try above code in visual studio 2015 edition  it says :

> The type or namespace name **'PdfPageBase'** could not be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: did you have the spire.pdf.dll in your project reference?

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio says this when it couldn't find the required assembly in the project reference. Add a reference to [Aspire.PDF dll](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Spire.PDF/) to your project